# Did Ajamila go to swarga or attain moksha?

Tags: moksha, swarga

He called his son "Narayana" on his deathbed and that amounted to calling the god Narayana and that absolved him of all sins according to the story.  Did he go to Swarga or attain Moksha?

Answer (score 7):

Ajamila went to abode of Vishnu on heavenly car assuming form of Vishnu's attendant after casting his body.

After chanting name "Narayana"(name of Lord), Lord Vishnu's attendants appeared on spot and saved him from noose of Yama and his attendants.

**[Chapter 1](https://archive.org/stream/BhagavataPuranaMotilalEnglish/Bhagavata%20Purana%20-%20Motilal%20-%20English%20-%20Parts%201%20-%205#page/n785/mode/2up), sixth Khanda of Bhagavata Purana** says: (translated by Dr. G.V. Tagore)

> 27. Thus, the ignorant Ajämila led his life. When the time of death actually arrived, he thought of his young son called Näräyana.
> 28. (Then) he saw that three extremely terrible male figures with wry faces, and with the hair on their bodies standing erect, and with
>       nooses in their hands, had come to take him away.
> 29. With his senses greatly agitated, he called out in a prolonged loud voice, his son named Näräyana who was absorbed in his play-things
>       at a distance.
> 30. Having heard the repetition of the name of Lord Hari, their master, uttered by the dying man, the servants of Näräyapa immediately
>       rushed forward, Oh great King.
> 31. Angels of Vishnu (intercepted and) forcibly stopped the messengers of Yama who were dragging (thé jiva of) Ajämila, the husband of the
>       maid-servant, from the interior of his heart.
> 32. Thus prevented (from carrying out their duty) the messengers of Yama demanded, ' 'Who are you who thus defy the order of Yama, the god
>       presiding over righteousness.

Vishnu's attendants said chanting name of Lord at death time destroys all sins  at death time (syllables of name of Lord are powerful enough to destroy all sins).

Vishnu's attendants said the following to Yama's attendants: (**[2nd chapter](https://archive.org/stream/BhagavataPuranaMotilalEnglish/Bhagavata%20Purana%20-%20Motilal%20-%20English%20-%20Parts%201%20-%205#page/n791/mode/2up), 6th Khanda of Bhagavata Purana**):

> 13. Hence, do not carry him ( the jiva of Ajämila) by the wrong way (the sinner's path leading to Yama's abode). He has completely
>       expiated all his sins. (When even a syllable of the Lord's name is
>       sufficient to annihilate all sins), he has uttered the complete name
>       of the Lord when he was about to die (and there is no time and hence
>       possibility of committing a sin after articulating the Lord's name) .
> 14. (As to the objection that Ajämila called his son and and not Vishnu, messengers explain). The experts in Sästras say that utterance
>       of the Lord's name even if taken to denote another person, or in a
>       friendly joke or as an insertion during the recitation of a song, or
>       in (an outward, apparent ) disrespect"', completely annihilates all
>       sins.

After explaining, Vishnu's attendants disappeared from spot and Ajamila contemplated on the discussion and got Vairagya and through yoga he casted off his body on banks of Ganga.

> Sri Suka said :
>
> 39. In this way, through a moment's association with the pious (servants of Vishnu), he felt a thorough aversion to worldly life (and
>       its pleasures) and freeing himself from all ties (to his mistress,
>       children and property) , he proceeded to Gangädvära.
> 40. Settling down in that sacred place (the abode of God), he betook himself to (the path of) Yoga. He withdrew (from worldly pleasures)
>       all his senses and organs, and concentrated his mind on the self.
> 41. Then, he dissociated his self from ( the product of) the gunas viz. the body, sense-organs etc., and by concentrating his mind, he
>       fixed it on the Supreme Brahman, which is the essential form of the
>       Lord and is the embodiment of consciousness, and bliss.
> 42. When his mind and intellect were thus ( thoroughly) stabilised in the Brahman, the Brähmapa visualized before him those very male
>       figures (messengers of Vishnu) , and recognizing them as those as
>       having been seen before, he stood up and bowed down his head (to pay
>       respect).
> 43. After that vision, he cast off his body at the sacred place (Haridvära) in the Gaigä and immediately assumed the (angelic) form of
>       the attendant of the Lord.
> 44. Along with the servants of Lord Vishnu, the Brähmapa ascended' the heavenly car made of gold and proceeded through heavens to thé abode
>       of the Lord of Sri (i.e. Visnu).

Comment: Skandha not khanda

Comment: @moonstar is there difference between Khanda and Skandha? Skandha is branch but Skanda Purana divisions are called khandas.

Comment: Divisions of Mahabhagavatam are called Skandhas. Vishnu Purana are called Amshas, Ramayana are called Sargas. We should not change the names of the divisions. @moonstar is right.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma "Ramayana are called Sargas."  Then why Ramayana is famous for "kanda" like sundara kanda?

Comment: @KrishnaShweta Chapter is called Sarga and Divisions are called Kandas. Chapters can't be called Adhyayas similar to Bhagavad Gita and Vice versa

Answer (score 4):

Ajamila attained moksha:

> Accompanied by the order carriers of Lord Vishnu, Ajāmila boarded a golden aircraft. Passing through the airways, **he went directly to the abode of Lord Vishnu**, the husband of the goddess of fortune. (Bhagavata Purana 6.2.44)

Since, Ajamila had chanted "Narayana", he attained moksha as promised by Shree Krishna in the Bhagavad Gita:

> And **the one who, at the last moment, while leaving the body, departs, contemplating upon Me alone, attains My abode**; of this, there is no doubt.(Bhagavad Gita 8.5)