# What are the examples for sadhakas who achieved results through 'nama' japa in scriptures?

Tags: scripture, moksha, nama-japa

There are several ways in Sanathan dharma to achieve the ultimate moksha. They are Yoga marga, Bhakti marga, Gnana marga, and mantra Japa, etc., Although they are not mutually exclusive, one can be attained by the other at different levels of sadhana.

Nama Japa is one of the paths to achieving both temporal and eternal result(s).

Scriptures contain many examples of sadhakas who achieved liberation with different paths. I am not saying that they did not follow other paths during their sadhana. Although some may use other paths as required, their main path can be a different one.

Suppose Janaka became a Jivan muktha by Gnana marga. Gopikas are the best example of Bhakti marga. Sudarshana is an example of the mantra Japa. Similarly, there are several mentions of sadhakas of some other margas. Although Ajamila can be taken as an example for Nama Japa, I feel it's not complete as [he might not get moksha](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/26835/did-ajamila-go-to-swarga-or-attain-moksha).

Is there any example for people who get liberation through Nama Japa as the key sadhana? Please provide an example from the scriptures only as we can see my sadhakas from the history of India. So, please don't answer it with people names like Samarth Ramdas, Ramakrishna Paramahamsa, Tulsidas etc.,

Comment: there was one in bengal who got vision of Mother by naam japa alone

Comment: @hanugm:  As an example, Dattatreya's Spirit  is so uniformly spread throughout the universe, that by his own declaration and testimony of many disciples closer in time to us ( so are stronger than the Scriptures ), He can be called *Smarthrugami* or the One who comes to you by mere wishful or directed thought. The names of such devotees are included in *SreePada SreeVallabha Charithamritham.* A perhaps less known way of Bhakthi is that the Spirit as much desires the Bhaktha as the Bhaktha desires the Spirit's blessing.

Comment: Valmiki who wrote the Ramayana

Comment: Dhuruva , Prahlada upakyaya/(charitram ) , as part srimad Bhagavad Puran  may also be included in the ans. to theis ques .
Predicament of Mj. Duruva, and how resorts to grace of Lord, thru Narada Maharishi etc .
https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/4/8/40/ and following verses .. and in a specific stanza, part of Dhurava stuti it is said, though Lord is a Kalpa taru, who can bestow bhavApyaya-vimokshaNam, only temporal bhogas are sought-after .

Comment: @Athrey Do you mean [this](https://prabhupadabooks.com/sb/4/9/9)? How is it related to the question?

Comment: yes ..Viveka of eternal and ephemeral , emphasize d in this verse, is  essentially  known to sadhak of highest order seeking  liberation , SB seem to detail path of nama japa for liberation thru Dhuruva, Prahalada chrithram, so IMO , is relevant to the ques.